# Postgres computed fields (views or triggers)

Tags: postgresql

I want to have a couple of *computed* fields on a table, which are aggregations from child tables. For example:

```
Categories
| id | name |

Items
| id | categoryid | name |
```

I'd like to have an *itemcount* column on categories, which is just a sum of the count of items belonging to that category.

In order to achieve this, I'm thinking either a **view** which appends this column. Then possibly add some rules to redirect inserts/updates/deletes back to the base table.

Alternatively I could create a trigger which rules whenever something is added to the **Items** table to update the **Categories** table.

Is there a conventional best practice when requiring such data?

Comment: This may be a silly (clarifying) question, but wouldn't you also want deletions on the categories table (or the categories view) to be denied unless the itemcount is zero?

Comment: @Wildcard that would definitely be the case, but I think I'd leave it up to the database foreign key to prevent those types of cascading deletions. Then return a meaningful error to the user about it.